# In order to compare different CNNs , should they be trained on same dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new in machine learning so a i am  wondering about two things. First one,  which parameters to use when comparing CNNs.
Second , sould they be trained on same dataset?

Comment: What is the purpose of the comparison? How are two different CNNs implemented? What kind of data are you using to train and test them with?

Comment: I am creating emorion  recognition. Fer2013 dataset. One model iz  mini_xception and another is simple cnn model based od cifar10 from keras site

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a comparison between any model/architecture, they should posses same condition such as `training-setting`, `dataset`, `parameters`, `optimizer`, `weight initialization`, etc. If there is any mismatch, the result can be biased. Following is some scenerio, how the result will be misleading for comparison.

1. If dataset posses different `distribution`, then model will have different behaviour and representation. For example in SVHN and MNIST dataset, both are used for digit classification. But their properties are completely different.
2. If one model is trained on large dataset(of same type, let's say `imagenet` vs `mini-imagenet`), one will learn better representation and generalization over other.
3. if one dataset is good in term of `quality`(resolution), then it will help in extracting better feature.
4. **Even same type of dataset, but collected using different cameras** will give different result.
5. Another feature such as `optimization` process are highly dependent on training setting(parameters).

**In conclusion, for any kind of comparison(to get a fair result), they should be evaluated under the same conditions**.

Answer (score 0):

They **definitely** should be trained on the same dataset as cnns train by learning the pixels. The pixel values would change if the dataset changes therefore there can be no concrete identifier to evaluate the models. You could also refer to any architecture papers like resnet where the paper shows the exact way to evaluate the models.